# How do I limit the number of posts displayed to one?

Tags: posts

I have searched Stack and the codex but can't find a simple solution for limiting the number of posts returned to one using the following:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=24'); ?> 
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php the_field('alert'); ?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=24&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
```

But using query_posts is a **[very bad idea](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)**.

This is straigt from the Codex:

For general post queries, use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

It is **strongly** recommended that you use the [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter instead, and alter the main query by checking [is_main_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dejo for the correct answer on this. I just wanted to post what this would look like using the get_posts approach he mentions above:

```
<?php               
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 24 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_field('alert'); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```